# How way to move a file pointer to the next word in a text file?

Tags: c, file, text-files, file-pointer

I have a program that requires that I start from word N, hash the next N+M words (concatenated and done through another function so the original pointer is not moved), and then increment the FILE pointer that is pointing at N to the *next* word.

The only way I thought to do this was to increment the FILE pointer until a space is found, then increment further until we found the first character of the next word. This is necessary because the file I am reading may have multiple spaces between words which would not result in a matching string compared to a file that has the same word content but single spaces.

This method would then require `ungetc()` because we we would have taken from the stream the first character of the next word.

Any ideas on a different implementation or am I pretty well restricted to this method?

```
    while ( (c = fgetc(fileToHash) != ' ' )
        ;
    while( (c = fgetc(fileToHash)) == ' ')
        ;
    ungetc(c, fileToHash);
```

Comment: So basically you didnt do anything.

Comment: I do not see your point, valter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you insist on using the file pointer as your index, that's pretty much what you've got. A better solution would probably be to read part or all of the file into a buffer and manipulate your pointer into the buffer, unless you intend to do random-access overwriting of the file's contents -- which is generally completely impractical with text files.

Comment: I do not see the merit in first reading the entire file into a buffer. What is the difference in manipulating the pointer in a buffer relative to manipulating the pointer to a file? Wouldn't the buffer manipulating still require the processing each character as shown above?

Comment: Buffering theoretically reduces disk io. However, the OS is probably buffering the file anyway, so it may not make a difference .

Comment: You can perform MUCH tighter loops scanning a block of memory than making repeated function calls to fgetc().

Comment: @Johnny Mopp, The documentation on `ungetc()` says that the character put back into the stream does not effect the original file on disk. Perhaps this is alluding to a pre-buffered file? Or is there some pointer manipulation in which some type of temp buffer is used or something (thereby simulating putting a character back into the stream)?

Comment: Yes. The OS buffering is transparent to you. You also can control the buffering done by stdio.lib. Search setvbuf.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
void findWord(FILE *f, int n) {
    int c = 0;
    while (n-- > 0 && c != EOF) {
        do c = fgetc(f); while (c != EOF && !isalpha(c));
        while (c != EOF && isalpha(c)) c = fgetc(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fscanf to read words delimited by whitespaces. This example will read each word from standard input and print each of them on a new line:

```
char buf[128];
while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", buf) > 0)
    puts(buf);
```